# Model Reference to another project ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

There is a completed ASP.NET MVC project.

In that project, it already has the company employee main data.

So I want to create another project but, I don't think that creating another table in this new project for the employees and again saving the same details is an unnecessary thing.

So is there any way of accessing those data from another project?

As Example,

`Project 1` has a model called `EmployeeMain` and this project has CRM_UAT Database.

`Project 2` need to access the model called `EmployeeMain` from project 1 to create user accounts and save them in the `DCS_UAT` database.

So how can I handle this kind of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate project to handle the data access. and referencing that project with your project 1 and project 2 would be a good practice.

You may also look into clean architecture and repository pattern will give you a good idea.

https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/onion-architecture-in-aspnet-core/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

[image]

Comment: Hi! Any examples can you share? Project 1 is already in the production environment, Project 2 is the new one I'm willing to start freshly. So can you describe me in more detail how to do it without damaging anything in the live environment?

Comment: @DevBeginner please see in the answer. i have added few links.
You can create 2 projects(presentation layer) in a single solution  and refer it to same domain layer.  so that domain will be shared across the projects.
Consider marking it as answer if it clears to you. thanks